# How to read the contents from a text file url

Tags: php

Im having difficulty getting the contents of text file when Im trying to get the contents of that text file from a url.

Say my text file url is http://example.com/files/text.txt.

Whenever I try using file_get_contents('http://example.com/files/text.txt'), it returns the actual source html code of that url. Is there a way to just read whats actually written in the text file itself?
I do know that to do what im trying to is is very easy with just using the file path, however the files im trying to get sit on another server.
Any help with this? Thanks

Comment: getting the url, you will only retrieve  what the http server sends you, if its a php file you would get the results or output not the raw php. for *.txt it should not matter

Comment: Show us the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Not very intricate.. its really just like how I described it at the top. I have the url as a string and I try to receive the contents of the text file with file_get_contents();

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to said server you could use fopen function,  however that requires fopen to be enabled cross domain via php.ini. Also in your regards it could be the headers are returning as html as opposed to plain text.

Comment: The server im trying to pull the file from is an amazon s3 server, if that helps.

Comment: Also is there a way to check the headers you mentioned? And if so what I should be looking out for?

Comment: It was just a thought i mean i would have thought your method you used should have worked haha.  But you can check using developer tools in your browser.